# Accessing all children of an element the React way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to create a staggered fade in animation for some of my React components. I have written a way to do this with vanilla JS, but my project is written in React.

After a bit of research and asking around, I believe my solution somehow involves the useRefs hook, but I have to admit I really don't see how I could do it.

Here is the vanilla js code I have, what it does should be pretty intuitive.

```js
export const fadeInChildren = (parentClass, index, position) => {
    let parents = document.getElementsByClassName(parentClass)

    for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
        let children = parents[i].children

        for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                children[i].classList.toggle("fade-invisible", !compareArray(index, position))
                children[i].classList.toggle("fade-in-and-up", compareArray(index, position))
            }, 150 * i)
        }
    }
}
```

Excuse my use of this style of for, I am much more comfortable with it as opposed to forEach or for of

Comment: Just sharing this wonderful animation library for react that supports this staggering animation https://www.framer.com/api/motion/ hope you will find this helpful

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: Thnak you, khierl. I had previously taken a look at React-Transition-Group. At the moment I would like to understand the solution to this problem before using a package. Both due to the fact that this is a learning experience as well as a personal bias against lazy solutions for very small problems.